# Related Tags not in category

Tags: categories, tags

I'm using this piece of code to show related posts based on the tag of the post you are viewing.

I'd like to modify is a little to exclude the related posts from the loop if they are in the same category of the post you are viewing

Reason for this is i already have a loop to show related posts in the same category, so trying to cut out the duplicates.

```
<?php
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
  $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
  $args=array(
    'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'showposts'=>5,
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
   );
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <!-- loop here -->

      <?php
    endwhile;
  }wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very similar to what you do with tags. Retrieve IDs of categories for current post:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$cat_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $category)
    $cat_ids[] = $category->term_id;
```

Then exclude them in query:

```
'category__not_in' => $cat_ids,
```

Comment: Thanks. Had a feeling it was something like that, i just don't know enough php jargon.

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is keep a global variable that contains all post id's that you already showed in a "related articles" area, and pass that to `post__not_in`. This allows you to add and remove other ways to show related articles (by enabling or disabling widgets?), and always prevent duplicates.

Comment: This sounds efficient, but i haven't a clue how i'd do it.

Comment: @Blackbird: Very easy: when you loop to display each related item, add a line like `$wpse4770_displayed_related_post_ids[] = get_the_ID();` and pass that array to your `post__not_in` query argument.